# NumPy native way to store dictionary of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary

I'm looking to see if there is a more efficient way (i.e. using native NumPy functionality) to achieve what I'm doing currently.

My process is I start with an array `a`:

```
a = np.array([[0,2,0,-1],[-0.2,0,-0.1,0],[0,0,-0.1,0],[0,0,0,0]])

array([[ 0. ,  2. ,  0. , -1. ],
       [-0.2,  0. , -0.1,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. , -0.1,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ]])
```

I then filter based on where the values are not equal to `0`:

```
r_indices, c_indicies = np.where(a != 0)

(array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2]), array([1, 3, 0, 2, 2]))
```

From there, I create a Python dictionary `b` like so:

```
b = {i: c_indices[r_indices == i] for i in np.unique(r_indices)}

{
    0: array([1, 3]),
    1: array([0, 2]),
    2: array([2])},
}
```

I do this because I want to know for a given unique row index `r`, which column indices are ***not*** `0`.

My own preference is to try to use NumPy as much as possible to take advantage of speed benefits. However, I'm not sure how else to structure this in NumPy since the values in the dictionary could range from a length of `0` (no values are not zero) to `4` (all values are not zero).

Am I being paranoid about the potential speed benefits?

Comment: 1) Worrying about speed benefits is trading your time for the computer's time, and only you can decide whose time you care about more. 2) It seems you're storing summary statistics in a numpy array, and usually numpy arrays with only a few elements don't give a speed advantage. 3) As an aside which may not be relevant to you, I'd worry about lines like `where(a != 0)` when you're using floats because it won't match values not equal to but very close to zero.

Comment: `{r:np.nonzero(a[r]) for r in range(4)}` might be simpler and even faster.  `nonzero` on the whole array is faster, but breaking it into rows and making a dictionary is basically a Python task.  When collecting a list or dict of arrays that differ in size, it is difficult, if not impossible, to use whole-array methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Pandas` in the following way:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

if __name__=='__main__':
    a = np.array([[0, 2, 0, -1], [-0.2, 0, -0.1, 0], [0, 0, -0.1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]])
    rows, cols = np.where(a !=0)
    x = list(zip(rows, cols))
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=x)
    l = df.groupby(0)[1].apply(list)
    L = [np.array(a) for a in l.values]
    d = dict(zip(np.unique(rows), L))
```

**Output**

```
{0: array([1, 3]), 1: array([0, 2]), 2: array([2])}
```

As pandas works with `numpy` under the hood, this code will be much more efficient than the regular list comprehension.

Also, if all you need is a dictionary-like object - you could inhance the performance further by using the `l` `Pandas.GroupBy` as:

```
l.loc[0]
```

which will result in :

```
[1, 3]
```

which is equivalent to the `b[0]` in your example.

and omitting the last two lines altogether, as `Pandas` provide a very fast mechanisms for handling large amounts of tabular data, and generally preferable to a plain `dict` object, if they used for the same thing.

Cheers.